# How to store "password" in SQL Server 2014 so no one including developer can retrieve/decipher?

Tags: security, password-encryption, sql-server-2014-express

We are storing passwords in datatype nvarchar(128)

[See how it stored in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbyAq.png)

We want to ensure no one including the internal team who has access to the server decipher or retrieve it. Can we do it?

Thanks
Sarah

Comment: May i ask why you are storing the passwords instead of hashing them?

Comment: Make a SHA-512 hash of the password. Of course, if the dev can interfere and alter the code, they could save the plaintext phrase before it is hashed...

Comment: What are those passwords? Are these passwords of your application's user's? Then hash them as suggested by @leberknecht. Or are these passwords you need to authorize with external applications?

Comment: [leberknecht]  Sorry, I don't have technical skills. I need to ask the developer.

Comment: [piet.t] What are those passwords? Are these passwords of your application's user's?  YES, it's the password of the user.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot. I am not sure whether a password has been stored or hashed! Please let me know how to find the difference. Thanks.

Comment: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: Thank you, Marek Puchalski. Appreciate it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The values in the screenshot look like base64 encoded values, which *probably* means they have been hashed. It's best to confirm that a proper password hashing function (see the [OWASP link][1] posted by Marek Puchalski) has been used, though.